# Force mount Fat16 partiton?

Tags: hard-drive, fat32

I have a Windows XP HDD that no longer wants to mount itself. Long story short, I tried to acces my data through a Ubuntu Live USB. The hard drive wouldn't auto mount, thus I created a mount point using:

> sudo mkdir /media/external

When I try to mount the HDD using

> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/external -o forcer

I get this error message:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>   dmesg | tail or so

How can I force mount my fat16 partition so that I can save my files?

Comment: What makes you think it's FAT16, btw? FAT32 was introduced in Windows 95, 6 years before WinXP.

Comment: Gparted says it is Fat16... It's my fathers HDD, I have no idea why he chose fat16.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify filesystem type explicitly:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda2 /media/external
```

(you can also try `fat`, `msdos` and `umsdos`). The particular format (FAT32, FAT16 or FAT12) should be detected by the driver automatically, however, you can override it with `fat={12|16|32}` option.

See `man mount` for more details on FAT-specific mount options.

Comment: I would replace "-t vfat" by fat, or msdos, or umsdos?

Comment: Yes, they're different drivers which share a common core/options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT_filesystem_and_Linux

Comment: Note that `vfat` will usually work for FAT16 and FAT32.